# Set Trigger on ALTER_SERVER_ROLE

Tags: sql-server

I've tried to add a trigger to the ALTER_SERVER_ROLE command using:

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER XXX
    ON ALL SERVER
    FOR ALTER_SERVER_ROLE AS
```

It creates fine but doesn't fire when using the ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] ADD MEMBER [Test]

Any ideas why it doesn't fire?

Using SQL2019 CU8

Answer (score 1):

OK, found it after sifting through the intellisense and trying everything that looked right

```
FOR DDL_SERVER_SECURITY_EVENTS AS
```